# Splitting up class definition in ES 6 / Harmony

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

Suppose I have a class in one big file like this:

```
export default class {
  constructor () {}
  methodA () {}
  methodB () {}
  methodC () {}
}
```

And I want to break up the class definition so that `methodA`, `methodB`, and `methodC` are each defined in their own separate files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to, as `class` is supposed to just be syntax sugar for the usual prototype workflow:

```
import methodOne from 'methodOne'
import methodTwo from 'methodTwo'

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
  }
}

Object.assign(MyClass.prototype, {methodOne, methodTwo})

export default MyClass
```

Comment: but what if I want have methods with properties? methodOne(a,b)

Comment: `methodOne` how to use `methodTwo` ?

Comment: @GeminiYellow Same as always, `function methodOne() { this.methodTwo() }`

Answer (score 8):

@elclanrs gave a correct answer, but I would modify it to allow for the use of `this`. I also think this is more readable.

```
import methodOne from 'methodOne'
import methodTwo from 'methodTwo'

class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.methodOne = methodOne.bind(this)
    this.methodTwo = methodTwo.bind(this)
  }
}

export default MyClass
```

Tip: although if your class is so large that it warrants being split into multiple files, a better solution might be to split up the class into multiple classes.

Comment: elclanrs' answer does allow the use of `this`; the only difference as far as I see is that the functions seem to be enumerable when using your method. This is usually not desired... (compared with nodejs util.inspect with tries on both answers)